# Render a promised value for each item in a mapped list

Tags: javascript, caching, es6-promise

I am trying to count the number of items in each cache, and render the results in a list. I can console.log() the result, but can't render it. In this cache 'tiles' there are 5 items. I've reviewed all the related questions but they all show how to console.log() a value from a promise which I can do, but I can't figure out how to render the value for each item in an array.

These are the components:

```
// Array passed to  Layers.js

const offlineLayers = [
  {
    title: "Demo Activity",
    url: "tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
    cacheName: "tiles",
    cacheLength: tiles.length // 2141 items
  }
];
```

````
// Layers.js - where the details about each object in ```offlineLayers``` are rendered

const getCache = async (cacheName) => {
  const cache = await (await caches.open(cacheName)).keys();
  return await cache;
};

{offlineLayers && (
    <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
      <FormLabel>Offline Layers</FormLabel>
      <RadioGroup value={baseValue} onChange={handleBaseChange}>
        {offlineLayers.map((layer, i) => {
          let length;
          getCache(layer.cacheName).then((cache) => {
            console.log(cache.length); // 5 which is the correct number
            return (length = cache.length);
          });
          return (
            <Fragment>
              <FormControlLabel
                className={classes.formControlLabel}
                key={i}
                value={layer.title}
                control={<Radio size="small" />}
                label={layer.title}
              />
              <FormHelperText
                className={classes.offlineCount}
              >{`Downloaded: ${length} / ${layer.cacheLength}`}</FormHelperText>
            </Fragment>
          );
        })}
      </RadioGroup>
    </FormControl>
  )}
````

I need `length` to render the number of items in the cache, for each object in `offlineLayers`. It console.log()s the correct number (5) but currently renders `undefined`.

[image]

Thanks for any suggestions on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has a similar problem, I solved it by appending the number of downloaded tiles to the original array before mapping it, which makes more sense than my previous plan to get the number of tiles for each layer during the map itself.

```
  const getCacheLength = () => {
    offlineLayers.map(function (obj) {
      caches.open(obj.cacheName).then(function (cache) {
        cache.keys().then(function (keys) {
          return Object.assign(obj, {
            downloadedLength: keys.length
          });
        });
      });
    });
    return offlineLayers;
  };

  const offlineLayersWithCache = offlineLayers && getCacheLength();

  // then map the new array offlineLayersWithCache as normal
```